# Indoor positioning using ARCore Geospatial API or ARKit from indoor 3D scan

Tags: arkit, arcore, indoor-positioning-system

How can you implement indoor positioning without using QR codes or image targets, but by using cloud anchors or geospatial API? Let's say you have the 3D scan of the inside of a building and want to implement indoor navigation for the place. How can that be done? (using ARKit or ARCore)

Something like the thing Google and Accenture did for marvel stadium: [Link](https://exchange.telstra.com.au/how-we-mapped-marvel-stadium-using-5g-with-google-and-accenture/)

Or like the area targets in Vuforia: [Link](https://library.vuforia.com/environments/area-targets)

Answer (score 1):

Its very unlikely you can use geo spatial api for indoor navigation since it fundamentally relies on gps. You won't most likely be getting good accuracy with it.